# Why can domain users query services remotely?

Tags: windows, permissions, service

I've set up a test domain with a Windows 2012 domain controller, and a Windows 7 client. The domain user 'User1' is logged on to the client machine, and is only a member of Domain Users:

```
C:\Users\User1.HYPERION> net user User1 /domain
...
Local Group Memberships
Global Group memberships     *Domain Users
```

This user is not a member of the local administrators group on the domain controller:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> net localgroup Administrators
...
Members
----------------------------------
Administrator
Domain Admins
Enterprise Admins
```

Why does this domain user, logged on to a client, seem to have permission to query services on the domain controller?

```
C:\Users\User1.HYPERION> sc \\DC qc spooler
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS
...
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Authenticated Users have permissions to query services, as defined on the security descriptor of those services.

Have a read at the link for more info:

http://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/